# Поиск и взятие строки с целой страницы регуляркой

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть страница:

```
Главная - <a href="[DOR_URL]">Главная</a>
УРЛ-[DOR_URL]

<br><br>
[LAST]<img src="[IMG_L]">[KEY_L] (кей шорта) = [CONTENT_L](контент)[/LAST]
<br>
[LINKS]
 <a href="[LINK]">[TEXT_L]</a>
[/LINKS]
<br>
[PAG]
```

Хочу получить содержимое (все что между) *[LAST][/LAST]*

Моя регулярка что-то умрямится:(

`preg_match('/\[LINKS\](.*)\[\/LINKS\]/', $page,$str);`

Отдает пустой массив

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это из за перевода строки в входном тексте. `.` по умолчанию соответствует любому символу кроме перевода каретки, добавьте модификатор "многострочный" (`s`) после закрывающей косой выражения:

```
preg_match('/\[LINKS\](.*)\[\/LINKS\]/s', $page,$str);
```